# How do write_image requests in OpenCL get clampped?

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL you need to define a sampler objected when doing image reads (read_image*), and in that sampler you specify how addresses are clamped (e.g. you can do CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE). But there is no sampler for image writes (write_image*). So there is no clamping specified.
What is supposed to happen to pixel addresses that exit the image boundry then? Is that just not specified and left up to the vendor? 
Looking on the web, it seems most OpenCL code that has write_images either does not use any clamping or people use their own clamping functions. I don't understand why the clamping is unspecified for writes, but specified for reads. Am I missing something here? I've googled and double read the specs, there's nothing explaining how writes are clamped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OpenCL 1.2 specs, 6.12.14.4:

> The behavior of write_imagef, write_imagei and write_imageui for image
>   objects created with image_channel_data_type values not specified in
>   the description above or with (x, y) coordinate values that are not in
>   the range (0 ... image width – 1, 0 ... image height – 1),
>   respectively, is undefined.

There is no write clamping, and it's left to the user kernel code to ensure coordinates are valid.

Comment: Damn it. I did not see that. Thanks!

Comment: In my experience with NVIDIA and AMD devices, writing outside an image does nothing. So you don't have to check for out of bounds before you write. I think the texture unit just discard the write operation in some way.

Comment: @Erik it leads to crash on some nVidia hardware like gtx 480 using nVidia SDK 5.0

Answer (score 3):

No only is there no image write clamping, on some devices (e.g., older NVIDIA hardware), writing outside image bounds *will crash* in often hard-to-debug ways (since it's a GPU crash). Avoid doing this.